# How do I bring Cockram and Burgess closer together?

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

In Sequence 9 Memory 2, one of the optional objectives is to double assassinate your targets, Burgess and Cockram. In my many attempts, I have not once seen them closer than a few metres apart, far too distant for any kind of double assassination. Even when they reach their ship and stop moving, they put 2 men in between them.

How am I supposed to bring these two together before I kill them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key to this mission is patience.  As long as you are not detected, after you have found your targets (actually see them), they will start to take a predetermined route around the town.  They will be walking around together so they should be easy targets to air assassinate when in range.  You should not get detected during this part of the mission otherwise you'll get everyone riled up and your two targets will stop taking that route and split up.

You should (silently) take out guards that are covering the roofs or are within visual range of them.  That way you can easily get into position to the nearest roof when they come by.  Then lie in wait for them to get close enough and air assassinate them.

If you're having difficulty taking out enemies silently, take advantage of your sleep darts (and not your berserk darts) so you can close in and finish your targets easily.  You don't necessarily have to take them out one at a time.  If you spot a group, shoot them all with darts and finish them off.

I recorded a quick video demonstrating how easily this can be done:

Comment: I've tried patience a few times and all I got in return is Cockram and Burgess standing at the dock in front of their ship with 4-5 guys between them and not moving an inch afterwards

Comment: You have to get close enough for you to hear them talking. They'll have a conversation as they walk around and won't start moving until you get within hearing distance.

Comment: I added a video killing them. Oddly, when I recorded this, it was a lot easier than when I first attempted this. :D

Comment: That is a much better method than my one I reckon. I hadn't noticed that quick route into the treetops at the beginning which would seem to help a lot. :)

Comment: I'm not sure patience is the right word. You go pretty quickly to where they start without waiting around much. I tried patience and slowly killing people I thought would get in the way and as a result I was totally out of position when they start walking and it isn't long before they are going door to door and separate enough that the double kill becomes a nightmare (and see my answer for the tedious approach I then had to take). :)

Comment: @Chris: Yeah, I know. Like I said, this pass I made in the video seemed a lot easier than I last remembered. Last time, I approached from the right side on the ground so I had to deal with guards along the way to the guard tower in the center. Going that way required a fair bit of patience. This one on the other hand was much easier.

Answer (score 6):

**Gunpowder method.**
I was having similar trouble with this today. However I might have found another method. While stalking the two targets I was spotted and all hell broke loose. I tried to hide but to no avail, they were on me like glue. I spotted the gunpowder barrels near where a large group of soldiers parade. Standing next to the barrels I took aim and waited till the two lads got close and blew us all up. This also counted as a double assassination. Provided you're not very low on health this could be a last resort if you get seen like I did.

Comment: This was the method that worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably a little late for this, but I just got into the game and was having trouble with this too.

After screwing up many, many times, I eventually got aboard the ship while they were on the docks.  I play very slow and cautiously, so this happens every time for me.  I carefully climbed the rigging and... screwed up, and they came onto the ship and fought me.

So what I did was drop a smoke bomb, kill some scrubs, smoke bomb, kill scrubs, and repeat until only the two targets were left.  I hit one with a sleep dart, brought the other guy near him, and hit that one with a sleep dart.  A short climb half way up the rigging and they were both available for a double air assassination.  Easy.  Stupid, counterintuitive, and I daresay badly designed for such an objective, but easy.

If you don't mind exploiting AI and implying that in a true historical event Edward Kenway lured two men onto a ship, put them asleep, and then dove at them like some damn lunatic from a story and a half up, go for it.  It bugs the living hell out of me to do it this way, but it's done.

Answer (score 2):

This mission took me a really long time to figure out how to actually get them close together. I actually used this video's strategy (along with the help of sleep darts) to double assassinate them from the rooftops.

Hope this helps.

EDIT: It should also be mentioned that there is a point in this mission where they stop going around homes and station themselves separately, around the docks (if I remember right). If this happens, immediately restart the memory to the last checkpoint.

Answer (score 1):

This mission was a pain in the ass and I had many attempts. I think near the beginning when they are walking through town I've seen them close together but for me I could never find a time to get close without being spotted.

In the end the way I did it was to wait for them to get to the ship and then swim round and climb on the ship unnoticed (slaughtering thousands on the shore on the way).

Once in the rigging I used berserk dates on the mooks to get them cut down. At some point during this one of them noticed me but  I kept going til there was only the two left.

In one attempt I then put one of them to sleep (they were reasonably far apart) and the other saw him and came to wake him up. I then tried the double assassination jump but it seemed the one who woke up was immune (or for some reason the game didn't consider him to be valid for double assassination despite them being right next to each other) and I only got one. With the right timing I think this would work though.

The way I actually did it though was that while I was on a platform on the mast (I used the front mast in case it matters and occasionally saunted down ropes to get in dart range) and they were milling about below and just happened to get close to each other at one point and I managed the double.

I kept thinking there must be some better time that is properly designed for it but if there was I couldn't find it unless there is a way to get them right at the beginning of their walk.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely a pain in the ass objective, worst part is if you enter either of their LOS for even a second you are instantly in combat, no yellow meter.  When that happens I think it's virtually impossible to get this done, even if you manage to get away and hide as soon as they are done searching for you one of them will flee and the other won't and you'll fail if he gets too far away.

I managed to do this without patience (because I have none).  If you go down the part of the hill where you slide down you'll end up in bushes with a guard right in front of you as well as the bell.  Kill the guard and then go to the right of the path behind the houses towards the ocean.  When the path curves, both guys should be coming right around the corner.  The last house on the right (looking towards the ocean) will have some brushes you can hide in very close to the path.  One guy will go check on the house on the left while the other waits in the path, when he returns from checking the house this is where you can get them.  When he gets back to his friend they'll stare at each other for a second, so don't go right away or you'll be spotted.  As soon as they turn to start walking, immediately sprint out of the bushes and mash square or X and you'll get a running double assassination.  If you wait too long then the will start checking houses and be surrounded by dozens of guards and you'll have to pull something off by the dock.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, after I figured it out it really easy but need to be done exact step.
- after help 2 pirates, go to watch tower(view point) and jump off the roof into haystack.
- wait for the first guy come nearby, killed him while in haystack then quickly jump out
- go to north there will be 2 guys, just running double assassinated them.
- go to the roof quickly went up north, you'll see camp and our target come out of the tent.
- jump into nearby tree, our target will walk pass under tree together, then you can do double air assassinated them.

Answer (score 0):

If you engage them in combat and manage to get them over by the gunpowder barrel  you can shoot it and kill both of them and survive if your health is high enough. The only problem is that one of them throws grenades so it might take a few tries

Comment: This seems to be the method already suggested by user76733.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you can just shoot them both in sequence using F. Start a fight with the whole grounp, kill every m@*&¨# and then pistol 'em up.

Answer (score -1):

I resolve this with a little bug/ glitch. When they are in front of the ship I engage them. I kill all the soldiers but not them. And when one of them throw me a bomb. They suicide and kill the other guy.

Answer (score -1):

As soon as you restart, slide down the bank, and assassinate the guard standing there.

Stay there. Just wait for the two bad guys to come right past you (roughly 20 seconds). Take a running assassination, and get them both in the back. Please avoid the two guards walking behind them.